# How to make Vuetify v-card-text single line?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using vuetify `v-card` and I need to apply ellipsis css so that it remains single line and ... comes in when it exceeds.

I have used the following css properties:

```
.headerClass {
   white-space: nowrap !important;
   width: 95px;
   word-break: normal!important;
   overflow: hidden !important;
   text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
}
```

And this is my `v-card-title`

```
<v-card-title class="body-2 pl-2 headerClass">{{data}}</v-card-title>
```

I've even applied text-truncate, but nothing happens

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can wrap text into a html block element to work

```
<v-card-title class="body-2 pl-2">
    <div class="headerClass">
        {{data}}
    </div>
</v-card-title>
```

CSS:

```
.headerClass{
    white-space: nowrap ;
    word-break: normal;
    overflow: hidden ;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: Well, this one worked.
Could you please explain why though?
What's the fault in my approach?

Comment: Of course!  `.v-card__title`  has `display flex` and `text-overflow: ellipsis` don't work on flex container.

Comment: On your orgiinal code if you add `display: block !imporant` to `headerClass`, you will see ellipsis works. Try it!

Comment: I think is better to add anothe html element because you maybe wants to add another vuetify component inside.